# Problem with libgstreamer0.10 when trying to install some software

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, gstreamer

I am trying to install a commercial scientific software, but I am getting an error while trying to run regarding `libgstreamer0.10-dev`. Specifically, the software is complaining that it cannot find `libgstapp.0.10.so.0`, which is apparently part of this libgstreamer library.

The problem, as I gleaned from other questions/posts on the web, including on Ask Ubuntu, is that Ubuntu 16.04 comes with `libgstreamer1.0-dev`, not with `libgstreamer0.10-dev`.

Some earlier suggestions were to simply get the old library, but when I try

`sudo apt-get install`, this is the error I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer.0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
[sudo] password for skumar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgstreamer.0.10-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer.0.10-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgstreamer.0.10-dev'
```

So the package is not available in the repository any longer.

How do I solve this problem? I am not an expert in Linux, so please be kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `libgstapp.0.10.so.0` in Ubuntu but there's [`libgstapp-0.10.so.0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgstapp-0.10.so.0&searchon=contents) (note the dash instead of the dot) in the package `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0`.

If this is no typo (like your other typos in the package names in your question) and your application really needs `libgstapp.0.10.so.0` that's a hint that it's not meant to work with Ubuntu or other Debian-based Linux distributions. You can try to work around that with a symbolic link and additional library search path:

```sh
cd /path/to/your/application
ln -s "/usr/lib/$(uname -m)-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0" libgstapp.0.10.so.0
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PWD" ./application-executable
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the typo. It was libgstapp-0.10.so.0, not the other one. The key was the package you mentioned. I did not know it was in that one. Is there a way to know? Thanks. And thanks for pointing out, I did click the grey box.

Comment: @SeshadriKumar: See [How do I find the package that provides a file?](/q/481/175814) I would have flagged your question as a duplicate of it if not for the typo in the file name.